# QT http setting a user agent

Tags: qt, http, qt4

```
void MainWindow::on_WowButton_clicked()
{
    http->setHost("pastebin.ca");
    http->get("/raw/2072840");
    QString paste(http->readAll());
    ui->textEdit->setText(paste);
}
```

Now, I want to set user agent for the get request. please tell the proper way to set a user agent .

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QHttp is obsolete and depricated. You are required to use QNetworkAccessManager instead.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager();
....
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setUrl(QUrl("enter url") );
req.setRawHeader( "User-Agent" , "Mozilla Firefox" );

mgr->get(req);
```

If you still want to use QHttp

```
QHttpRequestHeader header("GET", QUrl::toPercentEncoding("/raw/2072840"));
header.setValue("User-Agent", "Firefox 4");
http->setHost("qt.nokia.com");
http->request(header);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I am aware that its obsolete..but I its some old code. and I still want to set an user agent..